# Reusing variables declared and defined in parent module in terraform

Tags: terraform

Suppose in parent module

```
module "gcs_buckets" {
  source  = "something...aws or azure"
  version = "~> 1.7"
  project_id  = var.id
  names = var.names_0 
  prefix = var.prefix_0
}
    
variable "id" { type = string }
    
variable "names_0" {type = list }  
    
variable "prefix_0" {type = string }
```

---

I used in child module below format ,its throwing error

```
module "gcs_buckets_0" {
  source  = "../modules/buckets_00"
  version = "~> 1.7"
  project_id  = var.id
  names = var.names 
  prefix = var.prefix
}

variable "id" {
    type = string 
}

variable "names" {
    type = list  
}  

variable "prefix" {
    type = string  
}
```

Its throwing error, suggest me how to use variables in child module

Comment: What error exactly and what do you want to do? What do you mean by "re-using variables"?

Comment: suppose in parent module, i declared variables to pass to main.tf, in child module,iam using different variable. its throwing error saying id is not defined

Comment: How did it go? Is is still unclear why you can't inherit variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules **do not inherit** variables from the parent module. All modules are self-contained units. So you have to **explicitly define** variables in the child module, and then **explicit set** these variables in the parent module, when you instantiate the child module.

Comment: suppose in parent module ,i assigned value to variable, project = var.project_id, in child module i used project = var.project_id, its throwing me error. but if i change project_id=var.project_id, its working, y is that like that

Comment: @chandram I'm sorry, I'm not following your example. You could consider making a new question for it with reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

So terraform works based on the concept of **calling module** and the **called module**. If the called module has a set a variables for which inputs have to be defined externally, then calling module (or the root module) must provide the called module with the input values (provided it has defines the same variables as the called module).

For e.g, this is the calling module which passes in variable inputs by defining the same variables as the called module. Additionally, it also passes in the values through a *.tfvars* file.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}
module "ec2" {
  source = "../modules/ec2"

  region = var.region
  env_prefix = var.env_prefix
  machine_image = var.machine_image
  machine_tier = var.machine_tier
}
```